# Meteorjs method call return undefined even though having callback

Tags: mongodb, meteor

i'm playing with meteorjs and had a hard time trying to figure out what exactly happen to the async method i written.

```
//in methods.js
feedbackTag = new Meteor.Collection('feedbackTag');

Meteor.methods({
  searchTag: function (tag, collections) {
    var result;
    if(collections.toLowerCase() == 'feedback')
    {
    result = feedbackTag.find({tag: tag});
    }
    return result;
  }
});

//in client.js
  Template.executefb.events({
'keyup input#searchFeedback': 
  function(e) { 
    if(e.which == '13')
    {
      var tag = $('#searchFeedback').val();
      Meteor.call('searchTag', tag, 'feedback', function(err, data){
        //err returns:Internal server error, data returns undefined
        console.log(err, data) 
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I seriously had no idea why does it return an internal server error:500. Any advice please.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

I realised that the results becomes 'undefined' when it was called in the client side. However, if I called directly from client i.e.

```
var result = feedbackTag.find({tag: tag});
```

it returns me the data I want.

Any ideas how to get the results from methods class instead? Thanks

Comment: How is your project structured? If you aren't using the conditions Meteor.isServer or Meteor.isClient, you must have these files in /client and /server folders for them to work properly (methods.js would become /server/methods.js, client.js would become /client/client.js)

Comment: Hi, so sorry. this is only part of the code. The code does have Meteor.isClient and Meteor.isServer respectively. The problem is when I create the following method, and call it using Meteor.call with callback, it always return error 500.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding **.fetch()** to your collection call on the server. This will return an actual array of data, otherwise you're returning a cursor, like you would in Meteor.publish().

This might be what's causing the error.

```
    Meteor.methods({
      searchTag: function (tag, collections) {
        if(Match.test(tag, String) && Match.test(collections, String) {
          if(collections.toLowerCase() === 'feedback') {
            return feedbackTag.find({tag: tag}).fetch();
          } else {
            console.log("Should have sent feedback, sent " + collections);
          } 
        } else {
          throw new Meteor.Error(400, "Invalid inputs!");
      }
    });
```

I've modified your code a bit, because it would be wise to start throwing your own errors, and it would also be wise to use Meteor's new Match package to validate your inputs.

Methods will return *either* an error object or a response object. Usually you'll have a condition on the receiving end, instead of trying to show both like you did with console.log.

```
function(err, res) { 
  if(!!err) { 
    alert(err.reason); /* or console.log(err) */
  } else {
    console.log(res);
  }
}
```